# Aligning text against bottom?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a very hard time trying to figure out how to align my bottom border for my text to the bottom border of my header. Can anybody tell me how to do this? It'd be greatly appreciated. I've tried numerous things.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zevoxa/YeJc6/

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="/img/logo.png"/>
    <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*-- HEADER --*/

#header {
 top:0px;
 width:100%;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 background-color:#2C2E31;
 border-bottom:#242426 solid 2px;
 text-align:center;
}

img#logo {
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-bottom:20px; 
}

#nav ul li {
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 padding-right:20px;
 font-size:20px;


}

#nav ul li a {
 color:#FAFAFA;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-bottom:#FAFAFA solid 2px;
}

/*-- CONTENT --*/

body {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 background-color:#2A2B2D;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe set #nav to the bottom of #header simply with:

```
#nav
{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
height:20px;    //whatever height/size of text is needed
}
```

This tells it to align #nav, which is in #header, to go to the bottom of #header.

Comment: `bottom` will be ignored unless #nav is a positioned element. Removing the default 16px margin on ul explains the issue.

Comment: IMO `position: absolute` should be a last resort.

Comment: why is that? I use it all the time

Comment: There is an article here http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/absolute-positioning-pitfalls/ which discusses some of the pitfalls. It is not very detailed, I'm sure that there are other similar articles to be found.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the margin-bottom to 0px for the ul

```
    #header ul {
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YeJc6/6/

Answer (score 0):

In your case you just need to remove the bottom margin on your ul.

```
#nav ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```